# Entity identification through type and name

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

## Context:

I have a Minecraft world on mobile that I use for MLG practice.
In said world I have 2 NPCs: one for teleporting me to certain heights ( Y-levels, and the other for the more technical side (command-blocks, structure blocks and different backend stuff in a normal MCPE map)

## Problem

After testing the world many times, I need to move the NPCs, for a better experience. One of them is named "Trainer", and the other is named "Programmer".

I need to teleport the Trainer NPC to a certain coordinate. How do I do that?

I have tried both of these commands to no avail:

```
tp trainer ~ ~ ~
tp trainer Rapper303
```

I also thought about including some JSON parameters, like so:

```
tp @e[type: NPC, name: "trainer"] Rapper303
```

But as far as I know The JSON params only work for the java edition of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the incorrect selector. Try:

```
tp @e[name="trainer"] ~ ~ ~
```

It looks for `@e`, all entities, and `name="trainer"`, with the name *trainer* (case-insensitive).